# Appending to slice bad performance.. why?

Tags: performance, go, append, slice

I'm currently creating a game using GoLang.  I'm measuring the FPS. I'm noticing about a 7 fps loss using a for loop to append to a slice like so:

```
vertexInfo := Opengl.OpenGLVertexInfo{}

for i := 0; i < 4; i = i + 1 {
    vertexInfo.Translations = append(vertexInfo.Translations, float32(s.x), float32(s.y), 0)
    vertexInfo.Rotations = append(vertexInfo.Rotations, 0, 0, 1, s.rot)
    vertexInfo.Scales = append(vertexInfo.Scales, s.xS, s.yS, 0)
    vertexInfo.Colors = append(vertexInfo.Colors, s.r, s.g, s.b, s.a)

}
```

I'm doing this for every sprite, every draw. The question is why do I get such a huge performance hit with just looping for times and appending the same thing to these slices? Is there a more efficient way to do this?  It is not like I'm adding exuberant amount of data. Each slice contains about 16 elements as shown above (4 x 4).

When I simply put all 16 elements in one `[]float32{1..16}` then fps is improved by about 4.

**Update:** I benchmarked each append and it seems that each one takes 1 fps to perform.. That seems like a lot considering this data is pretty static.. I only need 4 iterations...

**Update:**  Added github repo https://github.com/Triangle345/GT

Comment: Growing more slices means more allocations. If the format of the data you're storing is in fact static, you can declare them statically so there is no bookkeeping to do.: `type Vec3 struct { X, Y, Z float32 }; type Vec4 struct { X, Y, Z, W float32 }; type Color struct { R, G, B, A byte }` and then you have `type VertexInfo { Translations, Scales [4]Vec3; Rotations [4]Vec4; Colors [4]Color }` (or maybe drop the internal arrays and use a `[4]VertexInfo` if it's all the same).

Comment: this is a good idea, i will try it when I get home

Comment: thought about this.. cant implement in this way in structs because they have to go in "arrays" for opengl cgo anyways.

Comment: Ah, bummer. It might also be that it's mostly GC making this expensive. Tuning memory layout makes sense to me, but it could also help to recycle with [`sync.Pool`](http://godoc.org/sync#Pool) or, if you have RAM to spare, using [`runtme.SetGCPercent`](https://godoc.org/runtime/debug#SetGCPercent) to make GCs less frequent at the cost of using more RAM.

Comment: @efel what do you do with the slices between frames? If you're setting them to `nil` it would cause reallocation on the next appends. You can set a slice to zero length and nonzero capacity with `a = a[:0]` - it will not reallocate if, for example, on the next frame the slice is the same length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) needs to create a new backing array if the capacity of the destination slice is less than what the length of the slice would be after the append. This also requires to copy the current elements from destination to the newly allocated array, so there are much overhead.

Slices you append to are most likely empty slices since you used a slice literal to create your `Opengl.OpenGLVertexInfo` value. Even though `append()` thinks for the future and allocates a bigger array than what is needed to append the specified elements, chances are that in your case multiple reallocations will be needed to complete the 4 iterations.

You may avoid reallocations if you create and initialize `vertexInfo` like this:

```
vertexInfo := Opengl.OpenGLVertexInfo{
    Translations: []float32{float32(s.x), float32(s.y), 0, float32(s.x), float32(s.y), 0, float32(s.x), float32(s.y), 0, float32(s.x), float32(s.y), 0},
    Rotations:    []float64{0, 0, 1, s.rot, 0, 0, 1, s.rot, 0, 0, 1, s.rot, 0, 0, 1, s.rot},
    Scales:       []float64{s.xS, s.yS, 0, s.xS, s.yS, 0, s.xS, s.yS, 0, s.xS, s.yS, 0},
    Colors:       []float64{s.r, s.g, s.b, s.a, s.r, s.g, s.b, s.a, s.r, s.g, s.b, s.a, s.r, s.g, s.b, s.a},
}
```

Also note that this struct literal will take care of not having to reallocate arrays behind the slices. But if in other places of your code (which we don't see) you append further elements to these slices, they may cause reallocations. If this is the case, you should create slices with bigger capacity covering "future" allocations (e.g. `make([]float64, 16, 32)`).

Comment: I tried putting all 4 iterations inside like this and it did increase fps by about 4.  However; I'm still losing about ~4 fps from creating this slice the way you mentioned, why??

Comment: @efel Seeing so little from your code I can't really tell. Maybe in other places of your code you append more which will need reallocation. If this is the case, you can allocate a bigger slice (e.g with `make()`).

Comment: Note in the `make([]float64, 16, 32)` ex, the 16 is the slice Len, and the 32 is the array (allocation) size. So it can be appended to up to 32 elements without needing to reallocate

Answer (score 4):

An empty slice is empty. To append, it must allocate memory. And then you do more appends, which have to allocate even more memory.

To speed it up use a fixed size array or use `make` to create a slice with the correct length, or initialize the slice with the items when you declare it.

Comment: Initializing with the items did save some fps but i'm still losing about 4 fps with initializing items.. This doesnt make sense how can doing only 4 iterations of 3-4 things cost that much cpu overhead??

Comment: @efel Did yoyu specify a length and/or a capacity when using `make`? If you're doing this every frame, then you should probably reuse a single slice instead of creating a new one each frame. Depending on how you create and use the slices Go might need to allocate on the heap and create garbage (both of which will slow you down in different ways).