# Builtin append vs. bytes.Buffer write

Tags: performance, go, byte, buffer

In the situation where I need to add an unknown amount of data to a slice of byte, let say in a loop, I could either way use the builtin function `append()` or create a new `Buffer` and use the `Write()` function.

Which method is fastest ?

Comment: builtin functions are generally faster than any alternative. I guess append will be faster in this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends to use case.
Here in both cases `bytes.Buffer` is faster than `append` (Samples: 1, 2, 3, 4).

Using `buf.Write(make([]byte, 16))` takes `4.6482659s`,
Using `buf = append(buf, make([]byte, 16)...)` takes `6.6623811s`.

For samples 5, 6:
Using `buf = append(buf, byte(i))` takes `445.0255ms`,
Using `buf.WriteByte(byte(i))` takes `1.4410824s`

---

And `bytes.Buffer` uses builtin function `copy` and it is fast:

> // Write appends the contents of p to the buffer, growing the buffer
>   as
>   // needed. The return value n is the length of p; err is always
>   nil. If the
>   // buffer becomes too large, Write will panic with
>   ErrTooLarge.
>
> ```
> func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
>   b.lastRead = opInvalid
>   m := b.grow(len(p))
>   return copy(b.buf[m:], p), nil
> }
> ```

---

`bytes.Buffer` takes 4.8892797s and `append` takes   7.7514434s

See these benchmarks:

1- Using `append`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := []byte{}
    data := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        buf = append(buf, data...)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    fmt.Println(len(buf))
}
```

output:

```
7.7514434s
1600000000
```

---

2- Using `bytes.Buffer`

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    data := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        buf.Write(data)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    fmt.Println(buf.Len())
}
```

output:

```
4.8892797s
1600000000
```

---

3- Using `bytes.Buffer` with `make([]byte, 16)`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        buf.Write(make([]byte, 16))
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t)) // 4.6482659s
    fmt.Println(buf.Len())     //1600000000
}
```

---

4- Using `append` with `make([]byte, 16)`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := []byte{}
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        buf = append(buf, make([]byte, 16)...)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t)) // 6.6623811s
    fmt.Println(len(buf))      // 1600000000
}
```

---

5- Using `buf = append(buf, byte(i))` takes `445.0255ms`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := []byte{}
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        buf = append(buf, byte(i))
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t)) // 445.0255ms
    fmt.Println(len(buf))      // 100000000
}
```

---

6- Using `buf.WriteByte(byte(i))` takes `1.4410824s`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        buf.WriteByte(byte(i))
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t)) // 1.4410824s
    fmt.Println(buf.Len())     // 100000000
}
```

---

And See:

[Appending to slice bad performance.. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264208/appending-to-slice-bad-performance-why)
[Where is append() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790311/where-is-append-implementation)
[Efficient appending to a variable-length container of strings (Golang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251900/efficient-appending-to-a-variable-length-container-of-strings-golang)

Comment: Seeing different results from the two answers, I tried to write my own according to my needs :https://play.golang.org/p/kyuX5qzaIG. The results shows that append is fastest  (append = 2.70 ns/op, bufferWrite = 9.32 ns/op). There must be an issue with your bench somehow.

Comment: @WilliamPoussier: in Tim Cooper answer in func: `randomSlice` try `return make([]byte,  rand.Intn(1<<10))` instead of `return make([]byte, 0, rand.Intn(1<<10))` using slice with zero length is not a good benchmark.

Comment: Indeed you are right. When i changed by test data to a non-empty slice, append is slowest than using a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in function `append` is faster, as shown by the following benchmark:

```
package x

import (
    "bytes"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

var startSeed = time.Now().UnixNano()

func randomSlice() []byte {
    return make([]byte, 0, rand.Intn(1<<10))
}

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    rand.Seed(startSeed)
    b.ResetTimer()
    var all []byte

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        all = append(all, randomSlice()...)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBufferWrite(b *testing.B) {
    rand.Seed(startSeed)
    b.ResetTimer()
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buff.Write(randomSlice())
    }
    all := buff.Bytes()
    _ = all
}
```

Results:

```
BenchmarkAppend-4           10000000           206 ns/op         540 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkBufferWrite-4      10000000           214 ns/op         540 B/op          0 allocs/op
```